# I'm using a web api for getting values by ID & Name, Getting data using ID is working but By Name is not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is my html :-
I want to fetch Emp details by using Id or by name. Hence I have written a web API.
I am using Id parameter which is working but when I am trying to fetch these details by using name it's not working not even get called. Is there anything wrong in parameter or controller action or return type??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>All Emp</h2>
        <ul id="Employee" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Search by ID</h2>
        <input type="text" id="EmpId" size="5" />
        <input type="text" id="EmpName" />
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
        <input type="button" value="Nam Search" onclick="findName();" />
        <p id="Empl" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var uri = 'api/Emp';
        //var uri = 'DefaultApi';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#Employee'));
                });
            });
        });

        function formatItem(item) {
            return item.Name + ':- ' + item.Age;
        }

        function find() {
            var id = $('#EmpId').val();
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id).done(function (data) {
                $('#Empl').text(formatItem(data));
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textstatus, err) {
                $('#Empl').text('Error :-' + err);
            });
        }

        function findName() {
            var name = $('#EmpName').val();
            $.getJSON('api/ByName' + '/' + name).done(function (data) {
                $('#Empl').text(formatItem(data));
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textstatus, err) {
                $('#Empl').text('Error :-' + err);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

****This is my WebApi.config****
Here http://localhost:61429/api/Emp is working as well as http://localhost:61429/api/Emp/3 but
```

http://localhost:61429/api/Emp/ApiByName/Sanky is not working!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
        );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also share your controller class for Emp?

Comment: It's solved, & it was happening due to calling signature ambiguity.